# Highcharts - Gauge chart with breaks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get breaks on a gauge chart along the axis. It looks like below -

[image]

I have my jsfiddle setup to achieve the above chart but the breaks aren't quite working - JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/arj_ary/1g0v9Lhg/42/

The notable part in the code is -

```
breaks: [{
          from: 100,
          to: 120,
          breakSize: 20,
          repeat: 10
      }]
```

Can someone help me in figuring out what exactly i am missing or how to get those 3 breaks in the chart.

Thanks in advance !.

EDIT: i was missing a broken-axis module. Loaded it now, still cant get 3 different breaks on the axes.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/broken-axis.js">
```

Comment: There is a error in console for as `y not defined`, did you check that?

Comment: Thank you!, that was some unwanted code. Cleaned up now, update jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/arj_ary/1g0v9Lhg/12/

Comment: It seems that broken axis doesn't work quite well for gauge charts. **Minimal demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p4pzz8db/ You can report that on github: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tybkev76/ but it's unsupported probably.

Comment: I was able to achieve this with just tickPositions. See Answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Set tick positions at 25, 50 and 75 and that should work in conjunction with pane object on a solidgauge chart -

```
var chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge',
                renderTo: this.el,
                width: this.chartWidth,
                height: this.chartHeight,
                margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
            },
            title: null,
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            pane: {
                size: '100%',
                center: ['50%', '60%'],
                startAngle: -135,
                endAngle: 135,
                background: {
                    borderWidth: 13,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    shape: 'arc',
                    borderColor: '#E6E6E6',
                    outerRadius: '90%',
                    innerRadius: '90%'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                lineWidth: 0,
                tickPositions: [25, 50, 75],
                minorTickWidth: 0,
                tickWidth: 10,
                tickLength: 28,
                tickColor: 'white',
                zIndex: 6,
            },

            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    animation: false,
                }
            }
}
```